# Date Query in Access Suddenly Stops Working

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a list of items I'd like to view by the date they most recently occurred. I am currently using this query.

```
SELECT Cleaning1, Max(Date1) AS most_recent
FROM CleaningLog
GROUP BY Cleaning1;
```

It worked yesterday when I was at work, but suddenly stopped working. It won't show to most recent date an event occurred for some of the items. I was wondering why this would suddenly stop working. I added date parameters to the four queries I have with this code. When that stopped working correctly, I decided to create a test query, without date parameters, and it still won't show me the most recent event that I typed in.

I tried playing around with the <, >, = signs in the date portion of the code, but nothing seems to capture the dates I added this morning. I should mention this is what I have for codes that have a date parameter:

```
SELECT Cleaning1, Max(Date1) AS most_recent
FROM CleaningLog
GROUP BY Cleaning1
HAVING Max(Date1) < Now() - 30;
```

What do you think would be a potential cause for this query to stop capturing dates? The dates in my database are not in chronological order, because I had to manually type in events that occurred in the past. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

It seems like it won't use the data after ID 89. It worked fine yesterday afternoon. I added from ID 59 on this morning. All of the data was added the same way, through a form:

[image]

Comment: The internal order of your dates is irrelevant, because there is no internal order.  You should show us sample data which makes your problem reproducible.  Off the top of my head, perhaps you entered some bad data.

Comment: Also, show us the design of the CleaningLog table. Often, such errors can be caused by using incorrect column types

Comment: Double check your date format and check for day/month swap

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I updated the description with pictures!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the description with pictures!

Comment: How is your date stored in your database. Is it an actual date type or a Text/String? I'm betting the latter, which means you'll have to cast the field as date in your query, or fix your table to store dates as date. *updating comment*: given your screenshots, you are definitely not storing these dates as a date type, so you can't sort on them properly until you fix that.

Comment: @JNevill I'm really not sure, I am super unfamiliar with access. They stuck me with this project at work because I coded something super simple once in excel and now every one thinks I can code, even though this isn't coding. But how do I change it to receive the dates as dates, not as text?

Comment: I think you would have good luck with Access's `DateValue()` function so you don't have to monkey with your table. It will slow the query down, but save you from having to clean your data. Try the first query like `SELECT Cleaning1, Max(DateValue(Date1)) AS most_recent FRom....` and see if Access can convert your string dates to actual dates right in the query. You may still want to invest the time into fixing the table (you would have to backup the data, go to table properties and change that field type to "Date", then load the table from backup using `DateValue()` to convert as you load).

Comment: @JNevill It's saying that the expression is too big to calculate, so just going to re-enter the data. When I make a new date column, I make it as a date/time, not a short text, correct?

Comment: That's a shame. Yea... make it whatever Access' date format is so that Access knows it's a date that's being stored in there and can sort it as such. Otherwise you end up with a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort, which is definitely not what you want. Good luck on the new projects! You'll be the expert in no time.

Comment: I'd agree with @JNevill.  A real date naturally formats to the right, while all your dates are formatted to the left of the field.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

Convert your text date to a true date:

```
SELECT 
    Cleaning1, 
    Max(CDate(Date1)) AS most_recent
FROM 
    CleaningLog
GROUP BY 
    Cleaning1
HAVING 
    Max(CDate(Date1)) < Date() - 30;
```